# Assign Argument to Variable Name in R

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to create a function that will take in an argument and create a column with the argument as its name. Please see sample function below, where I would like to create the function 'newFun' that will take in 2 arguments, a dataframe and a variable name X.

```
newFun <- function (data = df, varname = x) {
df$x <- 5
}
```

newFun(data = df, varname = AWESOME)

will create a new column called AWESOME in the dataframe called df

Comment: `data[[varname]] <- 5; data` should be the body of the function.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-data-frame-column-using-and-the-name-of-the-column-as-a-string-in-a-v)

Comment: Though you will need to call `newFun(df, varname = "AWESOME")` with a quoted column name.

Comment: Oh yeah, that too